# Showing a subset is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

How do I show if $A \subseteq B$, and $A$ is uncountable then $B$ is uncountable?

Comment: I think it's trivial enough that you can take for granted, but you can do a simple contradiction.

Comment: As a worshipper of simplicity, I have, as always, tried to give the simplest possible answer.  Did I at least succeed in making it simpler than the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Proof 1:** Here's a logical proof: $B$ contains $A$. Hence, $B$ contains an uncountable set, i.e., it contains a set with cardinal number larger than that of $\mathbb{N}$. Hence, as the cardinal number of $B$ is greater than or equal to that of $A$, $B$ has cardinal number larger than that of $\mathbb{N}$.
- **Proof 2:** *Proof by contradiction:* If $B$ is countable, then $B$ has cardinal number equal than that of $\mathbb{N}$. However, as the cardinal number of $B$ is greater than or equal to that of $A$, and $A$ has cardinal number larger than that of $\mathbb{N}$, we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

- **Proof 1:** If $B$ is countable, there exists a surjection $f : \omega \rightarrow B$. If $A$ is empty, then it certainly is countable. So assume $A$ is not empty. Let $a \in A$. Define $f' : \omega \rightarrow A$ by

$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) & \quad f(x) \in A \\
a & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$f'$ is a surjection. $A$ is countable.

- **Proof 2:** (AC) As $A$ is uncountable, there is an injection $f : \omega_1 \rightarrow A$. Hence $f$ is an injection of $\omega_1$ into $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $B$ is countable, so
$$
B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,\ldots\}.
$$
Now delete the ones that are not members of $A$.  For example, you might have these ones left:
$$
\{b_5,b_{13},b_{72},b_{986},b_{2003},\ldots\ldots\}.
$$
Then let
$$
\begin{align}
a_1 & = b_5 \\
a_2 & = b_{13} \\
a_3 & = b_{72} \\
a_4 & = b_{986} \\
a_5 & = b_{2003} \\
& {}\,\, \vdots
\end{align}
$$
Then $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$, so $A$ is countable.